# rpy2 conversion issue: rpy2.robjects.vectors.DataFrame was successfully created but was not found

Tags: r, pandas, rpy2

I have two pandas data frames, and I want to use R package "cramer" to compare them in a Python notebook. Here are my code snippet.

```py
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
pandas2ri.activate()

from rpy2.robjects.conversion import localconverter

with localconverter(robjects.default_converter + pandas2ri.converter):
  first_component_r = robjects.conversion.py2rpy(first_component_2)

with localconverter(robjects.default_converter + pandas2ri.converter):
  second_component_r = robjects.conversion.py2rpy(second_component_2)

type(first_component_r)

%%R
cramer.test(first_component_r, second_component_r)
```

However, I got an error from the last line:

```
"WARNING:rpy2.rinterface_lib.callbacks:R[write to console]: Error in cramer.test(first_component_r, second_component_r) : 
  object 'first_component_r' not found"
```

I am confused. I know I cannot use `first_component_2` below `%%R`. But `first_component_r` is of `rpy2.robjects.vectors.DataFrame`. Why did it trigger the error? Any advices? Many thanks!

I want to create pandas data frames, and then convert them to R data frames, and then use them with a R package. I expect the three steps can be done in a Python notebook.